# Shell script to delete a set of files

Tags: shell, unix

I am running a simulation which results in a large number of files. The files are named like this: `a-*000.dat, a-*100.dat.....a-*500.dat....a-*900.dat`, where * is a two digit number.I want to retain a-*000 and a-*500, and delete everything else. 
I tried `rm a-*{100,200,300,400,600,700,800,900}` and it worked. But I have to run this for every value of *. Can you suggest a shell script so that I can avoid running `rm` many times.

PS: Hope this question is clear, objective, and specific. Please consider giving specific feedback before deleting/flagging this question.

Madhukar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by:

```
rm a-*[1-4,6-9]00.dat
```

Regarding your attempt: `rm a-*{100,200,300,400,600,700,800,900}.dat`, I don't see why you need to run it for every value of the prefix. It should work fine if you type it literally -- with the `*` in place, and it's equivalent to my suggestion above (only a bit longer).

As a side note, if you really needed to perform the `rm` multiple times, this can be automated by using a `for` loop in a script.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought about it!

Answer (score 0):

You want bash's extended globbing which is detailed here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

The key is

```
shopt -s extglob
```

After this you can use regular expressions for globbing. Use with care and verify with ls before you wipe out everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -regextype posix-basic -regex './a-[0-9]\{3\}00.dat' -not -regex './a-*[0,5]\{1\}00.dat' - exec rm -i {} \;
```

looks ugly but extendable where basic regex is not enough.